# Tensorflow and JS, wrong tensor size

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

I am tinkering with tf for a future faec recognition project, I am trying to create some training data, this is what I came up so far:

```
const imageUrls = [
            [
                '........01.png', //correct path
                '........02.png',
                '........03.png',
                '........04.png',
                '........05.png',
                '........06.png',
                '........07.png',
                '........08.png',
            ],
            [
                '........01.png', 
                '........02.png',
                '........03.png',
                '........04.png',
                '........05.png',
                '........06.png',
                '........07.png',
                '........08.png',
            ]
        ];

        //LABELS
        const labels = ['one', 'two'];
        const labelToIndex = {};
        labels.forEach((label, index) => {
            labelToIndex[label] = index;
        });
        const labelIndices = labels.map((label) => labelToIndex[label]);
        const numClasses = labels.length;
        const oneHotLabels = tf.oneHot(labelIndices, numClasses);

        
        const eImages = await Promise.all(imageUrls.map(loadImageAndPreprocess));

        const xTrain = tf.stack(eImages); // Convert the array of tensors into a 4D tensor
        const yTrain = oneHotLabels.toFloat();

        //free mem
        tf.dispose(employeeImages);
        tf.dispose(oneHotLabels);
```

Image process function for reference:

```
    async function loadImageAndPreprocess(imageUrls) {
        const images = await Promise.all(
            imageUrls.map(async (imageUrl) => {
                const img = new Image();
                img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
                img.src = imageUrl;
                await img.decode();

                // Resize the image to a consistent size, e.g., 320x320
                const resized = tf.browser.fromPixels(img).resizeNearestNeighbor([320, 320]);

                // Normalize pixel values to [0, 1]
                const normalized = resized.div(255.0);

                // Dispose the intermediate tensors to free up memory
                tf.dispose(resized);

                return normalized;
            })
        );
        return tf.stack(images);
    }
```

Now both xTrain and Ytrain (i can see with print()) have wrong size, for example yTrain I think should be a 8,2 size (or 16,2??) but it's only 2,2. What am I doing wrong?